# How to create a transparent Android application which will take the entire screen (above the status/navigation bars)?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know, how to make my app to be transparent and covering the entire screen of an android device.

This means being on top of the status/navigation bars as well! (And please don't tell me to put my app in "fullscreen" instead as this is not the desired effect, I want the status bar to be visible BUT "under" my layer/app and still being able to handle touches!)

I am able to do something close by creating a view dynamically using this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView= new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("This text is above status bar!");

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams
        (
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            // Allows the view to be on top of the StatusBar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            // Keeps the button presses from going to the background window
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            // Enables the notification to recieve touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.addView(textView, layoutParams);
    }
}
```

Here `textView` is created dynamically then added to the window manager and the result is my text displayed above the status bar. So far so good! But how to make it working with my XML layout `activity_main.xml`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/Root"
>

    <!-- Complete layout here (buttons, textviews...) -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I tried so far has given me errors saying I already have a parent for my `Root` view when trying to add it to the window manager like so:

```
// Load the activity layout
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

// Get the layout root element
root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Root);

WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams
(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    // Allows the view to be on top of the StatusBar
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
    // Keeps the button presses from going to the background window
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
    // Enables the notification to recieve touch events
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
    // Draws over status bar
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);

layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.addView(root, layoutParams);
```

Or when I tried to directly set the layout params of my `Root` element using `root.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`, it gaves me an error saying that it cannot converts `WindowManager.LayoutParams` to `RelativeLayout.marginLayoutParams`.

I'm stuck, all your help will be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, considering all my searches about this matter, I found that what I try to achieve (put a layer on top of everything on the screen, meaning status and navigation bars), is no longer possible for devices with OS above KitKat (4.4)...

So I simply, with a big disapointment, abandoned this project for now. :(

Answer (score 1):

About the parent error you can do this:
    `((ViewGroup)root.getParent()).removeView(root);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a window with Type_application_overlay for the layout params, add FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE / FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE for good measures, PixelFormat.OPAQUE and SetAlpha of the components to (0). Then you can close the application (onBackPressed()) and use the window - you do need the relevant permission though ( SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW ).